# How can I perform SQL ORDER BY exposure, focal and iso (in numeric not string)

Tags: sql, sorting, floating-point, sql-order-by, numeric

The columns for Exposure, Focal, and Iso are not being sorted properly. It seems like they are all being interpreted as strings and sorted as such. For example, if I sort Exposure down, the values can look like this:

1/800, 1/800, 1/800, 1/80, 1/675, 1/640, 1/60, 1/500

If I sort the Focal, it can look like this:

1.4, 1.4, 1.4, 14.0, 14.0, 1.3, 13.0, 1.2, 1.2, 12.0, 1.0, 10.0

and if I sort by ISO, it can look like this:

800, 800, 800, 80, 80, 640, 640, 60, 500, 500, 50

EDIT: [My other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617110/postgresql-in-a-single-sql-syntax-order-by-numeric-value-computed-from-a-text-co) (and answers) for doing all this in one single sql query.

Comment: for ISO and Focal, I can just do ABS(field_value) but I'm not sure about the Exposure.

Comment: What does the table look like that is storing these values? If it looks like and quacks like a duck...

Comment: no it doesn't quack like a duck lol... the thing is I don't know how the value will look like coming into the function, just knowing it's a string.

Comment: You're sorting strings (`1/800` isn't a numeric value if it's stored in a table like that - if it were, it would be along the lines of `0.00125` instead). The same is probably true of the other values; the columns are probably defined as `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, or `NVARCHAR` depending on the RDBMS you're using. If you sort strings, they sort as strings because that's what they are. And @billinkc was trying to point out that "If it looks like a duck, and quacks like a duck, it's probably a duck". If it looks like a string, and acts like a string, it's probably a string.

Comment: Is this data stored in a database table or something else? If so, what RDBMS?

Comment: @billinkc: Since the title reads "SQL ORDER BY" and a tag reads "SQL", it's probably a database. :)

Comment: @KenWhite One would think so but at this point, I've given up on making assumptions about what users are doing in this world. Given the comment "don't know how the value will look like coming into the function, just knowing it's a string" I wanted to verify the tags synced with operations OP was attempting to perform.

Comment: @billinkc: Good point. :) I've been unpleasantly surprised by some of the questions here, too. Probably good to be cautious and confirm.

Comment: My other question (and answers) for doing all this in one single sql query.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7617110/postgresql-in-a-single-sql-syntax-order-by-numeric-value-computed-from-a-text-co

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this on Oracle

```
with 
   w_data AS(
      select '1/800' exposure from dual union all
      select '1/80'  from dual union all
      select '1/675' from dual union all
      select '1/640' from dual union all
      select '1/500' from dual 
   )
select *
  from w_data
 order by 1 / to_number(substr(exposure, 3, length(exposure)))
```

For focal you do `ORDER BY to_number(focal)` and the same for ISO.

Note that exposure example will only work if first 2 characters are always '1/'. I can rewrite it for more general case, like '2.9/700', if you wish